# CalendarView Prototype

Tags: java, javascript, prototype

I want to use the calendar from http://calendarview.org/ to select a date and take that date to send to a servlet which gets information on that week.

How can I get the value of the date that I select? When I look in the HTML it is not in there. Is it set using some AJAX? If so how do I get that value? And is there some way to automatically call a servlet after a date has been selected?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you can call whatever javascript can call once a date is clicked, if it uses AJAX, it may not need to..., Just know you can create a similar dynamic calendar with very simjavascript.